# What is the best way to send data from a python script on a raspberry pi to a place that a chrome extension could access?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, google-aiy

So I'm working on an attendance system using an AIY Voice kit which I've programmed to when I say "Ok google, take attendance" It starts listing names and when you say here or absent, then it sorts them into 2 separate arrays. I made a chrome extension to put in the people who are absent to the website we use, but I need a way to connect the 2 to have a list in my chrome extension. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend not using a chrome extension for this in the first place. It seems needlessly awkward and complex.

Comment: I think its the only real way that I can. I need a way to automatically input data to a website and I'm not really sure if there's another way to do that.

Comment: Oh boy, today’s your lucky day! There are a bunch of solid options, including [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/) which is a headless browser you can control entirely programatically!

Comment: It looks great but I have absolutely no idea what it is or how to use it. Sorry I'm kinda a noob at stuff like this

Comment: No need to apologize! Unfortunately, I think a general introduction to this sort of task this falls outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Not all hope is lost, however, since you should be able to find plenty of good guides and tutorials on the subject of _browser automation_ using your search engine of choice. Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Comment: You could use the requests module in some way to do this

Comment: Unfortunately @AlexanderCécile, I'm not sure I'll be able to use browser automation because I'm creating this for teachers at my high school and I'm not sure that I would be able to use this at the school on their network.

Comment: @WilliamFlinchbaugh I would suggest checking, just to be sure. Personally, I would be extremely surprised if they were alright with a google AIY running off a raspberry pi, plus a chrome extension and whatever it takes to communicate between the two, and not okay with (more?) Python on the pi in order to run a browser or send plain network requests. I don’t know much about chrome extensions, but I imagine that the solution using that would be quite similar anyway.

Comment: This is where it would be great to have more information on the whole setup.

Comment: Either way, the bigger issue is still transferring the data to the actual pc or extension or whatever. I'm thinking the best way to do it is using a json because it can be read and written to by js and python. I still need to find a way to transfer the json somehow.

Comment: @WilliamFlinchbaugh Well that will depend entirely on where you’re sending it lol. If you’re doing straight network requests or browser automation (i.e Selenium), you don’t need an _actual computer_ unless that particular raspberry pi is really underpowered.